# How to integrate the reward point in magento 2 environment?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, reward-points

I have enable the reward points in `stores-> Configuration-> customers-> Rewards` section to enable the module. Based on the below screenshot i have implement the reward point. But I cant unable to get the reward point section in checkout page.enter image description here

[image]

[image]